# What version of PHP can I use to connect to a SQL Server 2000 database?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2000

I had a set up for connecting to a SQL Server database, but when I tested it on a SQL Server I came to find out that my current method will not work because the SQL Server version is out dated (2000), IT has no interest in updating so it makes it hard for me to do anything but use older versions.

I was wondering what version of PHP I could use so that I can connect to that server? I have 5.4 right now and I'm running the version that uses sqlsrv_connect. I'm wondering if going to a version that uses mssql_connect would work instead and what versions would be able to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php

"This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later."

So anything 5.2.x and below. However you should note that 5.2 and lower is no longer supported and won't even get security fixes.

Ideally you really should look into upgrading your 13 year old SQL server, it is not supported by Microsoft any more. I'd try and push IT on this.